Concatenar texto y variables cmd
¿Cómo puedo concatenar texto y variables en un archivo BAT?
@echo on
set fecha = %DATE:~6,4%.%DATE:~3,2%.%DATE:~0,2%
set carpetaBackup = "d:\backups\"
set logFile = %carpetaBackup%mysqldump_%fecha%.log
set configFile = "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.4\my.ini"
set archivoBackup = "%carpetaBackup%BackupDB_%fecha%.sql"

echo %carpetaBackup%
echo %fecha%
echo %archivoBackup%

IF EXIST %carpetaBackup% (ForFiles /p %carpetaBackup% /d -7  /c "cmd /c del /q @file")

IF NOT EXIST %carpetaBackup% ( md %carpetaBackup% )
IF NOT EXIST  %logFile% ( fsutil file createnew %logFile% 0 )


mysqldump --result-file=%archivoBackup% --log-error=%logFile% --all-databases -uroot -p XXXX 

pause

He intentado poner entre comillas el texto pero no resulta.

Qué querés concatenar?

Esto funciona.
Nada de espacios en la declaracion/asignacion de la variable:
@echo Off
set fecha=%DATE:~6,4%_%DATE:~3,2%_%DATE:~0,2%
set carpetaBackup=d:\backups\
set logFile=%carpetaBackup%mysqldump_%fecha%.log
REM set configFile="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.4\my.ini"
set archivoBackup=%carpetaBackup%BackupDB_%fecha%.sql


IF EXIST %carpetaBackup% ( ForFiles /p %carpetaBackup% /d -7  /c "cmd /c del /q @file" )

IF NOT EXIST %carpetaBackup% ( md %carpetaBackup% )

IF NOT EXIST  %logFile% ( fsutil file createnew %logFile% 0 )


mysqldump --result-file=%archivoBackup% --log-error=%logFile% --all-databases -uroot -pXXXXXXXX 



Si hubieras respondido mí pregunta te podríamos haber explicado mejor. Claro, set toma en cuenta cada espacio por lo que dará resultados indeseados si  dejas espacios alrededor del igual. Y para asignar un texto que tiene espacios y caracteres especiales lo debes hacer así: set "variable=...". Consulta esta página
